# Download file on button click

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I have a application where a button click needs to download a text log file. I wrote the backend API, but am not able to connect it from the frontend button click. Working on Angular 2 and C#. What changes do I need to make to component.ts file?

Button code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" [hidden]="!dbtn" (click)="GetMigrationLog()" id="downloadLog" translate>Download Log</button>   </div>
```

Here is my backend api code:

```
[Route("GetMigrationLog")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetMigrationLog()
        {
            try
            {
                IDBMigrationDataBo data = _serviceLocator.Resolve<IDBMigrationDataBo>();
                var result = data.GetMigrationLog();
                string logFileName = string.Format("Migration_{0}.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
                return StreamResponse(result, logFileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex.Message);
                return this.HandleError(ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done somthing similar .. it's a little bit difficult .. i share my experience and my code with you .. hope it helps you!!

in your html 
Download Log

in your ts:

```
 saveFile(id: string, name: string) {

    this._orderService.DownloadRicetta(id, name).then((result) => {
      this._toaster.pop('success', 'Download', 'Ricetta Scaricata con Successo');
    }).catch((err) => {
      this._toaster.pop('error', 'Download', 'Errore nel Download della Ricetta!')
      console.log(err);
    });

  }
```

in your service file:

first of all import a package (installed with `npm i --save file-saver @types/file-saver`)

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
```

then write your method like this:

```
public async DownloadRicetta(id: string, name: string): Promise<Blob> {
    return new Promise<Blob>((resolve, reject) => {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('Accept', 'text/plain'); //just check the type you need

      this._http.get(environment.API_URL + `Order/${id}/Download/Ricetta`, { headers: headers, responseType: "blob", observe: 'response' })
        .subscribe(response => {
          try {
            let blob = this.saveToFileSystem(response, name);
            resolve(blob);
          } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
        });
    });

  }





private saveToFileSystem(response, name: string): Blob {
    const contentDispositionHeader: string = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');

    //for get original filename
    const parts: string[] = contentDispositionHeader.split(';');
    const filename = parts[1].trim().split('=')[1].trim();

    //get extension of the file
    const parts2: string[] = contentDispositionHeader.split('.');
    let ext = parts2[1];
    ext = ext.replace('"', '')
    //set mimetype
    let mimeType = Utils.extToMimeType(ext);

    const blob = new Blob([response.body], { type: mimeType });
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, name + '_ricetta.' + ext);

    return blob;
  }
```

file UTILS.ts:

```
export default class Utils {


  static extToMimeType(ext: string) {

    switch (ext) {
      case "pdf":
        return "application/pdf";
      case "jpg":
        return "image/jpg";
      case "png":
        return "image/png";
      case "txt":
        return "text/plain";
      default:
        return "";
    }
  }

}
```

AND ALSO BACK END (ASP.NET WEBAPI 2 ):

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Order/{id}/Download/Ricetta")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetBookForHRM([FromUri] string id)
        {
            try
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest };

                var order = await _orderService.FindAsync(xx => xx.Id == id);
                if (order == null) return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest };

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.RicettaUrl)) return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest };

                var user = await _aspNetService.FindAsync(xx => xx.Id == order.IdUser);
                if (user == null) return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest };

                var fileWithPath = $@"{user.GetUserRicettaDirectory()}/{order.RicettaUrl}";

                //converting Pdf file into bytes array  
                var dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileWithPath);
                //adding bytes to memory stream   
                var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);

                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = order.RicettaUrl.Trim()
                };
                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                return httpResponseMessage;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogException(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks man, your code helped understanding what I need to do.

Comment: it it helped you .. rate it if you want .. so people know it is correct .. very happy it helped you!! ;-)